# How can I change the background of a text in action bar?

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I have an contextual Action Bar which appears when elements from a `ListView` are selected.

It looks like this [image]

`Sample Text` is actually a button which `icon="@null"` and `title="Sample Text"`, which will do some stuff when clicked. How can I change the background of this button to another color, so that it gets more intuitive that it its actually a Button and not some text?

*(extra info)*
The menu is inflated though an XML, which is this menu below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_sample_text"
        android:icon="@null"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Sample Text"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can set your own layout on the 
action bar and then do whatever you want with the layout.

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_actionbar, null);
        ab.setCustomView(v);
    }

    // Keep a reference to the view so that you can manipulate the controls.
```

Comment: Down checks on a response without a comment on why or providing a better response are not helpful.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question. Read it again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a layout of your own and set it as the ActionBar view. In that layout your buttons can have any style you want. This is how I do it in my app:

```
final ActionBar abar = getActionBar();
View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null); 
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams( ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  Gravity.CENTER);
actionBarTitleTV = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_textview);

abar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
abar.setIcon(R.color.transparent);
abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Although it works, I was looking for some built-in way to do it. To create a fully custom ActionBar is too much right now! But thank you !

Comment: No problem. Though I sould tell you that It's not that much of a hassle. The only inconvenience is that in order to update the text of the action bar you have to do a (TextView)viewActionBar.findViewById() to get the TextView and set the new text. Other than that it's pretty much the same. Good luck!